# Files are not created when i run this code

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I have the following code:

```
List<String> suma = new List<String>();
if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/totalsold" + username))
     suma = new List<String>(File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "/totalsold" + username));
List<String> actual = new List<String>();
if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/totalsold" + username))
   actual = new List<String>(File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "/soldproducts" + username));
List<String> sumatotal = new List<String>();
if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/totalsoldadmin"))
    sumatotal = new List<String>(File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "/totalsoldadmin"));      
 StreamWriter vanzare = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "/soldproducts" + username);
 StreamWriter total = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "/totalsold" + username);
 StreamWriter totall = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "/totalsoldadmin");
```

Why the files vanzare,total and totall are not created after the code below is executed ?

```
 vanzare.WriteLine("Hello World");
 total.WriteLine("Helle World again!");
 totall.WriteLine("Hello World again and again!");
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Always cultivate the habit of using Using(){} block when your performing IO operations.

Comment: It seems to me that you're storing per-user data in the application startup path... if that's not a requirement why don't you check the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration (http://bit.ly/Aor3LW).

Comment: Using() block is the safest way to operate on the IO due to their nature of criticalness. So this block ensures that the resources used for those IO is release properly.

Comment: i used using() blocks but it does not work !!

Comment: Are you catching exceptions anywhere? Is this the actual code you are running?

Comment: No exception thrown in the code that i run!

Comment: Did you debug it? Suggestion: If you have no clue, and asking why, try to use old fashion debugging. Write a log file or pop-up a messagebox in every line of your code. An example; if File.Exists bla bla bla //use brackets{} and in brackets take a log like Messagebox.Show("This msg comes from First if"); something like that  will help you to solve problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you close the file? Writes to files may not immediately occur, since probably both .NET and the OS are caching and thus delaying writes. The file should appear immediately when you open the `StreamWriter`, though.

For short-term usage of a file (e.g. for writing stuff and then closing it) you should definitely use the `using` statement:

```
using (StreamWriter vanzare = new StreamWriter(...)) {
   vanzare.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

which will make sure to properly close the file immediately afterwards and not leave any unmanaged resources around longer than they are needed.

If you need to leave the file open for longer than a single method, then of course you have to do that manually. Make sure that when you no longer need the `StreamWriter` (and other `IDisposable`s) you call the `Dispose()` method on them.

Comment: Not only closing it, but also flushing it.

Comment: PedroC88, that will happen if you call `Close()` or `Dipose()` on the `StreamWriter`. Their code just doesn't look at all (missing `using` statements) like they're knowing that objects can be properly closed and disposed.

Comment: As per Microsoft Doc... you're right. Guess I'll be revising my own code now XD.

Comment: i did what you've said but it does not make any changes !

Comment: What has changed now that you accept the answer? I got the impression that it didn't help. (But neither did your question)

Answer (score 0):

You are using slashes im your file paths, which might not work, depending on what platform you are using.

Use the `Path.Combine` method to concatenate the path and the filename, it will use the path separator that is correct for the file system:

```
string sold = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "totalsold" + username);
if (File.Exists(sold)) {
  suma = new List<String>(File.ReadAllLines(sold));
}
```

Comment: that's not the problem , the problem is that vanzare,total,totall files are not created and the content is not wrote in it.

Comment: @EmilDumbazu: Are you sure that the files are not created? If the path separator is wrong they may be created in a different folder than you expect.

Comment: Slashes pose no problems on Windows, though (at least not at the Win32 API level. With built-ins of `cmd` it's a different matter). (of course, that's no excuse not to use `Path.Combine`, agreed on that ;))

Comment: I am sure ! I've been looking in different folders while running the app.